# In git, how one can record changes to a file after making changes that you'd never want committed

Tags: git

Scenario:

1. update a web.config for your own local machine specific details. *[git shows web.config changed]*
2. update index to assume-unchanged: `git update-index --assume-unchanged web.config` *[git shows web.config untouched]*
3. pause/do-work/hack away etc.
4. make a change to web.config that needs to be committed, unrelated to the above changes. *[git shows unchanged]* **Ideally, git could show the changes that are different from the changes that we'd definitely not want.

For the first step, Is there a way to check-in the changes that you dont want into the index, thereby showing that web.config isn't changed as far as git is concerned for the initial environment setup.  Something like `git update-index --ignored-update web.config`

And next, on step 4, have git diff web.config only show the difference between what was just checked into the index, and have *only those* changes show in diff and commit.

*Please note, I'm aware of git update-index --assume-unchanged and --skip-worktree, both of these options dont fit the scenario.  Assume-unchanged and skip-worktree wont see the changes in step-4.*

*And also, I know that this is an interactive git job, yes, I use that extensively, however, there's two problems... when assume-unchanged is used, the changed file is no longer detected as different.*

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You want some changes to be tracked by git and others not in the same file? index.html with my changes for my local only and then the changes on top of that that I need to commit?

Comment: Yes.  The first set of changes to web.config, you'd update the index to show git that the file isn't changed in a way that we'd want committed.  The second change to web.config would differ from whats in the index, and thereby git would show that web.config is changed.

Comment: In a sense, we're committing to the index only, without committing to the head.  And also, I wouldn't care if switching branches causes it to go out-of-whack.  I believe this is similar to assume-unchanged behavior anyways.

Comment: `git add -p -- web.config` might be of use here, but without testing, I'm not entirely sure whether you would need to do a `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged web.config` first or not...

Answer (score 1):

I believe git doesn't have that level of granularity.

What you can do is:

Update the index for git to reconsider the changes, stash your changes, apply your desired changes, commit it, apply the stash and disconsider again:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged web.config
$ git stash
#apply and commit your changes
$ git stash pop
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged web.config
```

When I had some local modifications that I didn't want to commit, I kept in my stash with a specific name.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the changes you don't want checked in, ["clean" and "smudge" filters](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) may be a good option.  These filters can transform a file in an arbitrary way upon checkout (e.g., insert a username and password into a database config file) and transform it again in a different way when adding it to the index (e.g., replace the real username and password with dummy placeholders).

For example:

```
# configure the clean/smudge filters
git config filter.userpass.clean \
    "sed -e 's/^user:.*/user: @USER@/' -e 's/^pass:.*/pass: @PASS@/'"
git config filter.userpass.smudge \
    "sed -e 's/^user:.*/user: myuser/' -e 's/^pass:.*/pass: mypass/'"
echo "/web.config filter=userpass" >>.git/info/attributes

# create web.config
cat <<EOF >web.config
user: foo
pass: bar
EOF
git add web.config

# make sure the clean filter works.  notice that it shows @USER@ and
# @PASS@, not foo and bar
git diff --cached 

# make sure the smudge filter works too
rm web.config
git checkout web.config
cat web.config # it should show myuser and mypass
```

Alternatively, you can turn off the assume-unchaged bit and do `git add -p` to stage some of the edits to `web.config` but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Revert the "assume unchanged flag"

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged web.config
```

Now you have a mixture of wanted and unwanted changes. You can commit the wanted ones using `commit --patch/-p`:

```
$ git commit -p web.config
```

This lets you interactively select the changes you want to commit. After that commit, only the changes remain in `web.config` which you do not intend to keep.

If some of the wanted and unwanted changes are close together (in the same hunk) you may be able to use the `s` command during the interactive commit (split the hunk into smaller ones). This cannot be done for some changes that are *too* close together. In that situation, separating the changes involves manual work. (That's a good case for making lots of little commits as you go along rather than allowing unrelated changes to accumulate.)